# Declare an NSString With Format Specifiers and use it as a URL to open in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, nsstring, string-formatting

I have an int containing a number. I am wanting to declare an `NSString` so I can use use format specifiers when assigning a value to it.

I thought it might be something like this:

> NSString[NSString stringWithFormat] myString;
>
> myString = [@"http://myurl.com/%d",myInt];

I gather this is not the case, so question one is: How do I declare an `NSString` that can handle format specifiers and then assign it a value using format specifiers? The purpose of this `NSString` is to hold a URL, exactly like the second line above.

Question two is, How do I then use this string as a URL to open in a `UIWebView`?
I assume I use something like this:

> [webView loadRequest:

Sadly, this is as far as my knowledge stretches. Is there a way I can tell my `UIWebView` (webView above) to use the `NSString` with the URL I mentioned earlier?

I intend on having the `NSString` as a global variable, as it will be assigned it's value inside a C function. And 'webView' will use it inside a (what I think is a) method. All of this code is in the same file, the Delegate.m file. It is all executed on launch of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Your string should look like this:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%d", myInt];
```

What you missed: adding the * to indicate a pointer, and thinking that you had to/could first state that the string would have a format and then later state the format. It all happens at once, creating the string with the specified format.

**Edited to add NSURL**

To create a url you're creating an object of class NSURL, like this:

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myString];
```

And then you create the url request:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
```

And finally, tell your webView to load the request:

```
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, many thanks that worked great, but i'm getting one error. It seems the NSString is not accessible outside the C function, where it assigned the URL. The last 3 lines of code you provided are executed during: "didFinishLoadingWithOptions". I get an error saying the NSString is undeclared. Is there a workaround? Many Thanks

Comment: You're right that the string will only be available inside the method where it was created. Where is it being declared now?

Answer (score 0):

For your first part:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%d", myInt];
```

Then, based on a tutorial from iphonesdkarticles.com:

```
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myString];

//URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```